# Renaming a project in NetBeans IDE, Why am I getting errors?

Tags: java, netbeans, rename

I copied a file named DepCalc_Starter that opens properly into the NetBeans IDE, and I renamed it DepInherit [(picture of the DepCalc/DepInherit file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RabdN.png).

I then opened up the NetBeans IDE, selected "Open Project", and then selected the "DepInherit" project [(image of what it looked like when I selected DepInherit as the project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zmKa.png). It then opened as "DepCalc", which was fine because I was going to rename it in the IDE itself anyways.

But my main problem lies in the renaming. I renamed the project to "DepInherit" [(screenshot of me renaming the project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scc75.png), but while renaming, the IDE throws an error with respect to a certain file in the "DepInherit" project [(picture of error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgjfI.png).

Can someone help me troubleshoot this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question here. If it's possible, also provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This way we can help better; also, provide code snippets instead of pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with Netbeans and other IDEs. I would recommend creating a new project and the moving all of the files over and renaming the classes. That has worked for me in the past.